# SSAS - script partitions possible?

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, etl, bids, ssas-2008

I was recently tasked with partitioning a large cube and I ended up creating 15 partitions on several measure groups. It's sped up the processing time considerably. This was done in BIDS on a development copy of the cube. My question is on deploying to the production cube. Some other changes have occurred in production while I was working on this and I don't want to overwrite them so I can't just deploy the development project to production. Is there a way for me to script just the partitioning I performed on the development cube and apply that script to the production cube?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can implement SSIS package to automate this task. A simple example could be found here http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-scripts/1622-script-to-automate-ssas-partition-management-sql-ssis

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the creation of partitions in your production cube using SQL Server Agent and the SSAS Partition Manager which can be downloaded from https://ssaspartitionmanager.codeplex.com/

With just a few lines of config, you can dynamically create cube and tabular partitions on your production server.